# How to map a txt by column and line with FileHelpers lib

Tags: c#, text, filehelpers

**I'm wondering how could I get the column items from a txt file and write it on a output after formated.**

This is my **input.txt**

```
DC   2INCL1   50000             20190802<
DC   2INCL2   50000             20190809<
DC   2INCL3   50000             20190816<
DC   2INCL4   50000             20190823<
DC   2INCL5   50000             20190830<
DC   2INCL6   50000             20190906<
DC   2INCL7   50000             20190913<
DC   2INCL8   50000             20190920<
DC   2INCL9   50000             20190927<
```

This is how I read **input.txt** in my c#:

```
string path = @"c:\Users\Dev-02\Desktop\usingFileHelpers\textfiles\";
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Cliente>();
var result = engine.ReadFile(path + "input.txt");
```

I know that static text files with any Delimiter as `,` I should use `[DelimitedRecord(",")]`

But in my case I need to read by column and line and after that write it on my **output.txt**

*I'm expecting this output:*

```
1> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL1   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/08/02<
2> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL2   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/08/09<
3> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL3   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/08/16<
4> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL4   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/08/23<
5> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL5   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/08/30<
6> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL6   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/09/06<
7> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL7   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/09/13<
8> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL8   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/09/20<
9> Type:DC   TypeWeb:2INCL9   ValueToPay:50000             Date:2019/09/27<
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives correct results :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Column> columns = new List<Column>() {
                new Column() { name = "Type", type = typeof(string), width = 5},
                new Column() { name = "TypeWeb", type = typeof(string), width = 9},
                new Column() { name = "ValueToPay", type = typeof(int), width = 18},
                new Column() { name = "Date", type = typeof(DateTime), width = 8, inputFormat = "yyyyMMdd", outputFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"}
            };

            List<List<object>> data = FixedWidth.ReadFile(INPUT_FILENAME, columns);
            FixedWidth.WriteFile(OUTPUT_FILENAME, data, columns);
        }
    }
    public class FixedWidth
    {
        public static List<List<object>> ReadFile(string filename,List<Column> columns)
        {
            List<List<object>> data = new List<List<object>>();

            string line = "";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    List<object> newLine = new List<object>();
                    data.Add(newLine);
                    int startPos = 0;
                    foreach (Column column in columns)
                    {
                        string col = line.Substring(startPos, column.width);
                        switch (column.type.ToString())
                        {
                            case "System.String" :
                                newLine.Add(col.Trim());
                                break;
                            case "System.Int32" :
                                newLine.Add(int.Parse(col));
                                break;
                            case "System.DateTime":
                                newLine.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(col, column.inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                                break;
                            default:
                               break;
                        }

                        startPos += column.width;
                    }
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
        public static List<List<object>> WriteFile(string filename, List<List<object>> data,  List<Column> columns)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                int rowCount = 1;
                foreach(List<object> row in data)
                {
                    string line = string.Format("{0}> ", rowCount.ToString());

                    for (int index = 0; index < columns.Count; index++)
                    {
                        line += string.Format("{0}:", columns[index].name);
                        switch (columns[index].type.ToString())
                        {
                            case "System.DateTime":
                                line += ((DateTime)row[index]).ToString(columns[index].outputFormat).PadRight(columns[index].width);
                                break;
                            default:
                                line += row[index].ToString().PadRight(columns[index].width);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine("{0}<",line);
                    rowCount++;
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
    public class Column
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Type type { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public string inputFormat { get; set; }
        public string outputFormat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a excellent solution but I have a question ... if some of the columns were different? I'll edit my question and you can have a look

Comment: You have data that is NOT VALID. When columns are not aligned vertically then you have a delimiter character like comma, semicolon, or tab. Your new inputs looks like TAB delimited, but there is no TAB.

Comment: are not number of "whitespaces" a valid delimiter? Would be possible if I use 3 different delimiters for validation?

Comment: No.  You have either fixed width data or delimited.  You have 4 columns of data and then one line only has 3 pieces of data (1,2,4) with 3 item skipped.  You end up with data in wrong column.  A space is a valid delimiter only when the rows have consistent data.  You data is not consistent.

Comment: Ok!! Thanks again for the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no spaces in the values, if you were to File.ReadAllLines(... in, you could do something like the following:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\MyFile.txt");  

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] cols = line.split(' ');
}
```

Then you can trim manipulate the values in the cols array as needed

Comment: Thanks for ur time, that was really helpful!!